# How to share Firebase Project with other people without giving them console access?

Tags: firebase

I'm looking to add on a few developers to assist in my firebase-driven mobile application.  I do not want to give them direct console access to my project (if possible), but I want them to be able to set up their own firebase project with all the details from mine pretty much.  I'm essentially going open source with my app.  What is the easiest way of doing something like this?

For example, if I was using another backend such as MSSQL, they could simply run a create script to create that database structure and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

To share the code with another developer:

1. Remove the Firebase configuration data from your project.
2. Share the code with them.
3. Include instructions to add their own Firebase configuration data.